# How to print an NSOutlineView with NSVIew.printView

Tags: macos, cocoa, printing, nsoutlineview

I want to print an NSOutlineView. The view is a subview of a window on screen. I noticed the NSView api call printView. So I tried it in a simple minded fashion. In my AppDelegate I have a call:

```
@IBAction func doPrint(_ sender: Any?) {
    globalOutlineCntrl?.outlineView.printView(self)
}
```

So with the window containing the outline on-screen,  I issued the doPrint call.

The outline on screen looks like this:
[image: Screenshot]
The doPrint call seems to work, but prints this:
[image]
Is there anyway to make this work? If not how else to print a subview outline?

Comment: Have you tried light mode? Do you want to print what's on the screen (pop-up buttons) or do you want to print a report?

Comment: I just tried light mode, and it actually printed the outline in readable form! I actually want to print out more of a report, it could be multi-page.

Comment: If you want to print a report then create an offscreen `NSOutlineView`, in code or loaded from a storyboard/xib. The view doesn't have to be in a window. Use the same data and maybe the same data source and delegate. Create a `NSPrintOperation` with `NSPrintOperation(view:)` and run this operation. Printing isn't easy, ask a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dark mode causes some issues with printing. The easiest workaround is to create a separate, programmatic view with forced light appearance, clone the required content and then print that view.

`view.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)`

Comment: Sorry, my answer also had `.darkAqua` instead of the correct `.aqua`. Lol and sorry.

Comment: This sounds like the way to do it, but my attempt doesn't work (prints blank page).
    @IBAction func doPrint(_ sender: Any?) {  
        let archivedView = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: globalOutlineCntrl!.outlineView as NSOutlineView)  
        let myViewCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archivedView) as! NSOutlineView  
        myViewCopy.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)  
        myViewCopy.printView(self)  
    }

Comment: I'll accept this answer and ask another question why the cloning does not work.